# Rows as columns keeping the value of that row

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I m working on sql server and stucked with how can I get the desired output.

I have the below as the source table.

[image: source image]

and I want the desired output as below.

[image: Desired Output]

Here is the Query to have source table.

```
   DECLARE @Temp TABLE(Capacity INT,CDate DATE,Name NVARCHAR(100))
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1,'4/14/2014','M24')
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1,'4/15/2014','M22')
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1,'4/14/2014','M24')
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1,'4/15/2014',NULL)
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2,'4/14/2014','F67')
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2,'4/15/2014','F31')
   INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3,'4/14/2014','M53')
   SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Can anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result but since you need to return multiple rows for each `Capacity`, you will want to use a windowing function like `row_number()` that will generate a unique sequence for each `Capacity` and `CDate` combination:

```
SELECT Capacity, [2014-04-14], [2014-04-15]
FROM 
(
  SELECT Capacity, 
    CDate, 
    Name,
    row_number() over(partition by capacity, cdate
                      order by capacity) seq
  FROM @Temp
) d
PIVOT
(
  MAX(name)
  FOR CDate IN ([2014-04-14], [2014-04-15])
) piv
ORDER BY Capacity;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32688/0)